# Please explain what this command means, it is really nightmare for me

Tags: sed

```
sed -e"s@uid=[0-9]*(@@g"-e"s@).*\$@@g"
```

I tried

`s`= search

`[0-9]*` = search only number starting with 0-9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sed` command uses `@` as delimiters for the `s///` (substitute, not "search") command without reason, which makes it difficult to read.

Assuming the missing space before the second `-e` is a typo, and giving the strings a bit more air for readability, we have

```
sed -e "s@uid=[0-9]*(@@g" -e "s@).*\$@@g"
```

This is the same as

```
sed -e "s/uid=[0-9]*(//g" -e "s/).*\$//g"
```

which, with single-quoted strings, becomes

```
sed -e 's/uid=[0-9]*(//g' -e 's/).*$//g'
```

(note `\$` → `$`), or

```
sed 's/uid=[0-9]*(//g; s/).*$//g'
```

So, this is calling `sed` with two editing expressions:

1. `s/uid=[0-9]*(//g`

   This substitutes any substring `uid=` followed by any number of digits and a `(` by nothing (it removes these strings).  The trailing `g` makes it do this for all non-overlapping matches on the line, not just the first, so that

   ```
   uid=1(a) uid=2(b)
   ```

   is transformed into

   ```
   a) b)
   ```
2. `s/).*$//g`

   This removes everything from the first `)` on the line to the end of the line by replacing it with nothing.  Note that `g` is not needed here as the expression is guaranteed to only match once due to the anchoring to the end of the line with `$`.

   Our example from above would be transformed from

   ```
   a) b)
   ```

   into just

   ```
   a
   ```

   which leads me to believe that the trailing `g` in each command was added without much afterthought (the second one is definitely not needed and the fact that the second expression simply deletes all from the first `)` makes the *first* `g` ineffective, unless you are dealing with data that has unbalanced parentheses).  These should likely be removed.

As a further example, the command would change

```
this is (line 1) of the file
hello world uid=09(a)  uid=213(b)
```

into

```
this is (line 1
hello world a
```

Without knowing more about the context of this command (where you saw it, what it's *supposed* to do etc.), it's difficult to say much more about it or to suggest improvements to it.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that it's trying to take a line/variable that contains something like this:

> uid=500(JohnSmith)

...and reduce it to something like this:

> JohnSmith

It's trying to extract a real/user name — from inside the brackets — by deleting everything outside the brackets, and the brackets themselves.

Of course the number could be any number, and the name could be any name.